# Obfuscate javascript generated by PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have an audioplayer running on my website.
Currently there's no problem with the player although I wish to obfuscate my javascript code.

The problem is that the javascript is called on a page which includes a php file.

the player.php contains:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('.player').plate({
        playlist: [
            <?php
include ('inc/trackimport.inc.php');
?>
        ]
    });
  });

 </script>
```

And trackimport generates (in a foreach for each $dj found in the database):

```
echo '{"title":"'.$dj.'", "artist":"'.$set.'", "cover":"http://domain.com/'.$imglink.'", "file":"http://domain.com/'.$djurl.'/Archive/'.$url.'"},';
```

Is there away to make this full code obfuscated?

Comment: there's not much to obfuscate... i suppose you could pack it into a string.

Comment: Can you provide a more in-depth explanation?

Comment: is there really any point - obsfication is easily undone

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use [one of these](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+javascript+minifier) PHP-based JavaScript minifiers. It's basically the same effect, but you can probably put in a configuration flag to make one of them run only when you want it.